# Swift error saying it cannot assign to property due to it being a 'let' constant

Tags: swift

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
public var captureDevice: CaptureDevice?

...

guard let captureDeviceTest = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession.init(
            deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera],
            mediaType: AVMediaType.video,
            position: cameraPosition).devices.first else {
                return
        }
        
self.captureDevice = captureDeviceTest
            
if let captureDevice = self.captureDevice {

   ...

   // This is where error occurs
   if captureDevice.isExposureModeSupported(.continuousAutoExposure) {
         captureDevice.exposureMode = .continuousAutoExposure
    }
```

The error I am getting is: `Cannot assign to property: 'captureDevice' is a 'let' constant`. I tried suggestion [here](https://medium.com/@sajalgupta4me/cannot-assign-to-value-is-a-let-constant-swift-1a55d829f5b2) to use `inout` but despite placing that in various places, it still didn't work for me.

Any swift experts can help me out here?

Comment: `if let captureDevice = self.captureDevice {` => `if var captureDevice = self.captureDevice {`?

Comment: @Larme - wow that worked a little too nicely. I feel so stupid I spent hours scouring online for this.

Comment: @smolkitty That won't actually work (I'm 99% sure) because you are just mutating a local copy. It will fix the compile error but the logic won't work. I've added an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the local variable `captureDevice`, not the struct's `captureDevice` variable.

Just replace the line causing the error to the following:

```
self.captureDevice?.exposureMode = .continuousAutoExposure
```

Note the `self.` before `captureDevice`.

You might think of changing the conditional binding to using `var` instead of `let`, but that won't actually work. This is because you are just mutating a local copy. It will fix the compile error but the logic won't work.

Comment: Will need to use optional chaining: `self.captureDevice?.exposureMode = .continuousAutoExposure`

Comment: @daltonclaybrook Good catch, overlooked that - thanks

Comment: Using `self.captureDevice?` also worked! Thank you @daltonclaybrook and @George

Comment: @smolkitty reiterating George's comment above: simply using `if var captureDevice` will not work, or if it does, is indicative of a larger problem.

Comment: @smolkitty Another one of my typos, fixed again :p